# Multiple parameter in IN clause of Spark SQL from parameter file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run spark query where I am creating curated table from a source table based upon values in parameter file.

**properties_file.properties** contains below key values:

```
substatus,allow,deny
```

**SparkQuery** is

```
//Code to load property file in parseConf

spark.sql(s"""insert into curated.table from source.table where 
substatus='${parseConf.substatus}'""")
```

Above works with single value in `substatus`. But Can someone help what shall i do if I need to use `substatus` in `${parseConf.substatus}` for multiple values from param as below.

```
spark.sql(s"""insert into curated.table from source.table where substatus in '${parseConf.substatus}'""")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equalto operator expects 1 value to be passed other than directly reading the value from parameter file who make in pass a one string. You need to break the values and then use IN clause inplace of equalto(=).

Comment: I followed same to resolve the issue. Posted my answer few mins ago. :)

Answer (score 1):

To resolve my problem, I updated my property file as:

`substatus,'allow'-'deny'`

Then in scala code, I implemented below logic:

`val subStatus=(parseConf.substatus).replace('-',',')`

`spark.sql(s"""insert into curated.table from source.table where substatus in ('${subStatus}')""")`

Above strategy helped in breaking the values in string to muliple parameters of IN clause.